# Top n elements in queue

Tags: algorithm, stack, queue

I have implemented a queue using two stacks and i want to find the top N percent elements in the queue.

For example:
The queue takes the element in this order `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20}`

Top 10% elements means 10% of 20 = 2

Hence the answer should be 19 and 20

There are two ways that i can think of

1. Sort the queue, claculate the number of items (X) the are N% and then grab the top X elements.
2. [Selection algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm). (I just came across this algorithm and its based on idea of quicksort. So I probably will have to copy the entire Queue into an array and then apply the algorithm)

Is there any better way to solve this?

Comment: "I have implemented a queue using two stacks" Are you interested in a purely functional solution or is this just an exercise?

Comment: This is just an exercise. Even an idea with comparison between algorithms will do. My above two approaches are O(nlogn) and O(n). Both seem to be pretty fast on an average. However i would like to know a better approach  to do it or quite simply if these are the only two ways and whether i should use selection algorithm or not

Comment: Are you looking for a generalization of the MAXQUEUE which can always provide MAX in O(1)? In that case, is N a fixed value for a given instance of the queue?

Answer (score 0):

A queue isn't the best data structure for that, as you should not access elements inside it (most of queue implementations don't even provide an access operator) so you shouldn't sort it. So, if you don't need the queue due to some other requirements, I suggest you use a plain array.

Sorting is a very time consuming process. As you read/insert into the queue elements you can compute their sum. Based on the known sum, the number of elements and the percent required, you can compute a threshold. Then, you need to iterate through the elements (if using a queue, you can extract them one by one) and display those greater than the computed threshold.

Answer (score 0):

You can use other data structures that keep the elements ordered. For instance you can use [skip list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list), ordered [tiered vector](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~goodrich/pubs/wads99.pdf) or some binary search tree.

In most programming languages there is a build-in RB tree, but alas you will not be able to make use of it. You need to add information in each node about the weight of its left and right subtrees.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a binary search tree / 'ordered set' in conjunction with your queue.

When adding an element to (the back of) the queue, you simultaneously add it into the set.
When removing an element from (the front of) the queue, you simultaneously delete it from the set.

In order find the top N% of the elements in the queue, you can loop through the set from the top element, until the next element doesn't fit into the top N% criteria. This is because the set maintains an ordered list of elements within your queue.

In addition, as your original queue structure is still present, you can still preserve the relative order of the elements in your queue.